# Error : agent.add() function is not working i.e not getting output value to user.In Google assistant

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Following code is working. But `agent.add()` function is not working, i.e not getting output value to user.

```
var ref = admin.database().ref().child("Table/"); 
var query = ref.orderByChild("RegId").equalTo(RegId.toString()); 
query.once("value", function(snapshot) { snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
  console.log(child.key);
  console.log("FirstName: " + child.val().FirstName); 
  console.log("Mobile: " + child.val().MobileNumber); 
  console.log("Email: " + child.val().EmailId);
  var name = snapshot.child("FirstName").val(); 
  agent.add(The student name is ` `+` name);`
});
```

`agent.add()` is not working but, `console.log()` is working fine in database logs.

Comment: After console.log(),Agent.add() is not executing and not showing output to user,But console.log() is returning values in Firebase Database logs,But i need to display these values to user In Google assistant app.

Comment: Where is `agent` defined in your code? Have you tried wrapping the call in a try/catch and console.logging the error to your Firebase logs?

Comment: Formatting of `agent.add(...);` line looks weird, is it correct? Shouldn't it be like `agent.add("The student name is"  + name);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `agent.add()` does have some syntax problems in it, that isn't the core of your problem.

You also seem to be getting a child of the snapshot called "FirstName" each time you go through the loop, which I don't think is what you want to do. But this also isn't the core of the problem.

The issue is that `query.once()` is an asynchronous call, and you're using a callback function to handle it. The Actions on Google library expects you to return a Promise to indicate you are making asynchronous function calls, so it knows not to return anything to the user until the call is completed.

The best way for you to do this is to have `query.once()` return a Promise, handle your processing in the `.then()` portion of the Promise, and to return the Promise/then chain in your handler.

I haven't tested it, but it might look something like this:

```
return query.once("value")
  .then( snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach( child => {
      let name = child.val().FirstName;
      console.log( 'FirstName: ' + name );
      agent.add( 'The student name is ' + name );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line has invalid syntax:

```
agent.add(The student name is ` `+` name);`
```

Should be quoted properly:

```
agent.add('The student name is ' + name);
// or if you're using es6:
agent.add(`The student name is ${name}`);
```

Look into a good code editor that highlights these errors for you. I use vscode.