# Error in Google assistant with voice based command not getting data from firebase Database or Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm doing a project using Google assistant in Dialogflow. When I ask for data, for example if I ask to get student details using register number [RegId], if I enter the register number by using keyboard I'm getting the data. But, if I say the register number, like 191611238, it is not getting the data in Google assistant.

```
function handleGetthedetailsofRegisternumber(agent){

const RegId = agent.parameters.RegId;

agent.add("please wait");
var ref =  admin.database().ref().child("Table/");
var query = ref.orderByChild("RegId").equalTo(RegId.toString());
return query.once("value",function(snapshot) {

 snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

  console.log(child.key);
  // name field

 console.log("FirstName: " + child.val().FirstName);
 console.log("Mobile: " + child.val().MobileNumber);
 console.log("Email: " + child.val().EmailId);
 agent.add(`The student name is  ` + child.val().FirstName);
```

Here, if I say get student data of 191611238, it will display only "Please wait" and not executing other part.

If I enter the Register number manually, not using voice, I am getting the Student FirstName.

I want to get Data by using both voice and manually. But, if I use voice I am not able to get data.

Comment: I assume that your code actually matches the answer provided in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694252/1405634), since the code you're showing isn't properly using Promises. But i don't think that's your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that your Intent is not correctly capturing the number when you speak it - only when you're typing it. You may need to add additional debugging to see what Intent is getting called and with what value when you try it by voice.

This could be as simple in your code as adding debugging like this:

```
const RegId = agent.parameters.RegId;
console.log('RegId',RegId);
```

You can also turn on logging to Google Cloud, which will log every request and response that Dialogflow gets and that it sends to fulfillment. Do this by selecting the gear icon, then scrolling down and making sure "Log interactions to Google Cloud" is enabled. You can then see the logs by going to the Google Cloud Console for this project or by clicking the link next to the switch.

[image]

Comment: May I know how to do that in Dialogflow code.If possible explain me in deatil.That helps....me